# Is it possible to unhide only part of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, vertex-groups

So I'm working on a mesh with sub-meshes, and as I work on various bits of the project, I hide other parts to make it easier to see what I am doing.

So I work on one thing and hide a few predefined vertex groups and a random group of vertices, and do more work. 
Now I want to make a change to one of the vertex groups, and I'd like to unhide **only** that vertex group.

I haven't found a way; has anyone else? Is this worthy of a feature request?

Comment: I liked all of the suggested changes to the title except the substitution of "dehide" for "unhide". "De hide" is what you get from a cow or pig.

Comment: Further, "unhide" is used in the Blender manual 118 times, "dehide" not at all. But thanks for the suggestion, anyway.

Comment: Border-clipping can also be handy in these situations (Alt+B)

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be interested in the [*Mask modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mask).

This modifier will hide everything except the specified vertex group, or the other way around if you have the *invert* icon selected. To hide multiple vertex groups, you can add multiple modifiers:

[image]

Make sure the modifier is enabled in edit mode (triangle icon).

Answer (score 2):

Since posting the original question, I have discovered a technique for doing this in edit mode that is different for the one proposed by Gandalf3.

When elements are selected and then hidden with the <kbd>H</kbd> key, those elements stay selected. When you unhide them using the key combination, <kbd>ALT</kbd> - <kbd>H</kbd>, all of the hidden elements are unhidden, and they are all still selected. But if after each group of elements to be hidden are selected, they can be assigned to a new vertex group, before being hidden. Now, when the hidden vertex groups are unhidden, they will still be selected, but any of the selected vertex groups can be deselected by using the deselect button associated that vertex group, and the remaining selected vertex groups can be rehidden by pressing the <kbd>H</kbd> key.

This can be a particularly useful alternative to the mask modifier, particularly when the modifier stack is already large.