# Name a group of faces / hide the group / call the Name later and un-hide that group

Tags: mesh, shortcut, vertex-groups

I've been working on a human model for a bit now. It's my first.

I want to select a group of faces in the nostrils (or any part of the character like an ear or the lips to work on the tongue or teeth etc), name the group of faces I have selected, hide that named group so that I can un-hide them later and work on them if needed.

An inverse select would come in handy too. I took a break on this project and forgot quite a few shortcuts.

So I guess, what is the best way to accomplish this? Or how can I name a portion of mesh to work on in detail without seeing anything else. Does it involve layers, moving pieces of mesh to another layer, and if so how to do it that way as well?

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/is-it-possible-to-unhide-only-part-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [vertex groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html?highlight=vertex%20groups).

Select the vertices you want to group. Then using the plus sign create a new group and **assign** the selected vertices to that group. 
Once a group has been created you can select it or unselect it easily.

To hide selected vertices press  <kbd>H</kbd> , to unhide press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out. That's exactly what I needed!