# How can I make certain vertices unselectable?

Tags: vertices

I looked around and couldn't find any answers on this, so I'd figured I'd ask here.

I'm making clothes for my player model and I wanted to know if I can make certain vertices non-selectable, similar to how in object mode you can click on the eye icon and said object vanishes. Is there something similar to that but for vertices in edit mode? That way I can still see the vertices but they won't move if I accidentally click on them.

I read somewhere that pressing H can hide objects but the problem there is that it hides them(obviously) but then I can't get them back so I have to undo it.

This would definitely save a lot of work as I could just make the body vertices non-selectable and then adjust the clothes so it fits naturally on the model(again because I'm no pro and I'm working on a player model for my first video game)

If anyone knows how to do this or in general has any advice to help, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Also because this model is for a game, I cannot upload or share the file, sorry :(

Comment: Alt+H allows to unhide

Comment: Cheers for that :)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/is-it-possible-to-unhide-only-part-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 2):

To avoid separating the vertices into a new object you can use **Vertex Groups**

Select the vertices you want to group.

Make a new vertex group (With the + sign) and **assign** the selected vertices to it.

To hide those vercices press <kbd>H</kbd>

To unhide press <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Once you've created and asigned vertex groups is very easy to select and unselect groups of vertices as you need. Vertex groups can be named, edited or deleted.

Vertex groups are also of particular importance if you are going to be using cloth simulation.

More information on the blender manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html?highlight=vertex%20groups

Comment: @MrZak indded. Corrected...

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty stupid but I found through google a tutorial that shows you how to separate selected vertices as other objects:

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-clothing-for-a-character-with-blender--cms-27059

Basically, you select the vertices you want as clothes and press P then select separate. This will turn the selected vertices into another object. This makes editing clothes a lot easier then trying to find the previous method that I thought was necessary :)

Comment: Yes, it's good that you mentioned this. Depending on one's needs it may be better to Separate, or better to Hide. Each method has its advantages. On a related note, it is also possible to use the Mask Modifier to hide parts of a mesh, even for Object Mode and rendering.